# Android: ViewPager's onPageSeletected() method logic is slowing down the swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm new to programming and implemented a ViewPager for the first time.

The ViewPager contains 2 Fragments. When someone swipes back from Fragment 2 to Fragment 1, I need to create some logic to check for changes. Here's what I have so far:

```
mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {


            if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {

            incentiveWindowReference.deActivateDeleteMode();
            TextView bubbleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bubble_text_xml);

            boolean hasActiveItems = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < incentiveList.size(); i++) {
                if (incentiveList.get(i).getActiveOrInactive()) {
                    hasActiveItems = true;
                }
            }
            if (hasActiveItems) {

                bubbleText.setText("Finish Pomodoros to unlock Incentives!");
            } else bubbleText.setText("No active Incentives!");

            if (!timerWindowReference.getCurrentlyBreaking()) {
                timerWindowReference.pause();
                timerRunning = false;
                Button startStopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                startStopButton.setText("START");

                timerWindowReference.activateResetSkip();}
            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

The problem is, this part is making the ViewPager laggy. If I comment it out, it is smooth. But I don't know how else I could do it.
If someone swipes from Fragment 2 back to Fragment 1 (or 1 to 0) and did some changes in Fragment 2, I need the bubbleText in Fragment 1 to change.

**EDIT:**

So i narrowed it down. Calling the method "deactivateDeleteMode" is causing the lag. This is the content of this method:

```
public void deActivateDeleteMode() {
    delete.setText("DELETE");
    addIncentiveButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mDeleteMode = false;
    setAdapter();
}
```

The problem seems to be "setAdapter()"

The reason i call setAdapter, is, that it fills the List with a different images when mDeleteMode == false. If mDeleteMode == true, it shows a trashbin icon and deletes the item on click. If mDeleteMode == false, it shows the normal image.

I want the deleteMode to be deactivated, if someone swipes away from the Fragment.

Comment: Roughly how big is ```incentiveList.size()```? Might want to consider caching the boolean value ```hasActiveitems``` and calculating it elsewhere.  The call to ```findViewById``` should be set outside this call back as well. Calls to ```findViewById``` are expensive. Curious what else could be happening inside some of your other function calls there, maybe a lot of other logic?  Basically, try to do repetitive work that you could do else where outside of the ```onPageSelected``` function and cache the results somehow.

Comment: Hey, i narrowed the problem down and edited my post.

Comment: i can't understand the your problem, i think you asking if some data change on fragment 2 you need to so text on fragment 1 ? right?

Comment: The user is on Fragment 2 and pressed the "delete" button. The adapter fills the list completly new, this time with trashbin icons instead of the normal icons (i didnt know how else i could change the images of the list items). The delete button changes into a "back" button (to leave delete mode). If the user forgets to leave delete mode and instead swipes to the other fragment, i want it to leave delete mode automatically (thats why i call "deactivateDeleteMode" in "onPageSelected"